# Is there any way PHP program access ASP function or via versa?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have a code where I would like to enscrypt ids. For example, if the id is "Plaza Mall" I want it to run encode that.

Now, some of my program uses ASP and some uses PhP.

There is a big problem there.

I want the exact same enscrypt descript mechanism to work in both. So both asp and php need to be able to call the same code.

What would be a good solution for that? How can I write a program that can be accessed by both PhP and ASP codes on the same server?

Actually I want the same snippet of code to be accessible from several sources if that's possible.

I suppose I can write 2 versions of enscryption and description. One in PHP and one in ASP. I am looking for better solutions.

Comment: you could write a webservice and call that from asp and php

Comment: how to do so? What is a webservice

Comment: How to ensure that the webservice is only accessible from the same server?

Comment: there are several possibilities to do that read about webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call PHP from ASP or vice-versa. You could use a webservice but that would be coded in either PHP or ASP and would require code which call that webserver on the back-end. That's not a great approach. And it is a lot of work to create a webservice from classic ASP.

Encryption and decryption are not to be taken lightly, just stick with a library, one for ASP and one for PHP. You could use Rijndael on ASP aswell as on PHP:

the ASP one: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2389

the PHP one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-open.php [I think but google will help you along]